# Simple http (including www) to https htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I want to verifiy that if my redirection code is implemeted good to dont have problems in seo.
Currently using this code:

I want to do this:

```
 - http://mydomain.tld to https://www.mydomain.tld
 - http://www.mydomain.tld to https://www.mydomain.tld
```

My currently code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Currently is redirecting but I dont know if 301 is implemented good?

Comment: If it works then 301 is just fine. Think of it as "final" redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned if a redirect is having a negative impact on organic rank, such as multiple redirects (rather than one clean redirect), you can use this tool to check each redirect 'hop':

[RedirectDetective.com](http://redirectdetective.com/)